Ajuste de lineas equipotenciales
Como parte de un experimento para un laboratorio de Electricidad y Magnetismo, nos pidieron medir ciertos puntos de varias superficies equipotenciales, los cuales debo graficar. Me gustaria agregar tambien las curvas, para que no queden los puntos sueltos. ¿Hay alguna manera de ajustar a una curva estos datos? Disculpen lo basico del planteo, pero intente algunos metodos con numpy, pero los puntos no respetan una función.

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x1=[-0.4,-0.3,-0.2,-0.2,-0.1,0,0,0,0,-0.2,-0.3]
y1=[-6,-5,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,5,6]

x2=[2,2,2.1,2.2,2.4,2.5,1.9,1.8,2.1,2.5,2.3]
y2=[0,1,2,3,4,5,-1,-2,-3,-5,-4]

x3=[-2,-2,-2.1,-2.2,-2.4,-2.7,-2.2,-2.2,-2.3,-2.7]
y3=[0,1,2,3,4,5,-1,-2,-3,-5]

x4=[-4,-4.1,-4.2,-4.2,-4.5,-4,-4.2,-4.4,-4.6]
y4=[0,1,2,3,4,-1,-2,-3,-4]

x5=[-1,-1,-1,-1.2,-1.1,-1.4,-1.1,-1.1,-1.1,-1.2,-1.3]
y5=[0,1,2,4,3,5,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5]

x6=[1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.3,1.3,0.9,1,1.1,1.3,1.4]
y6=[0,1,2,3,4,5,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

v1 = plt.plot(x1, y1, 'o',color="tab:red",label="V")
v2 = plt.plot(x2, y2, 'o',color="tab:green",label="V")
v3 = plt.plot(x3, y3, 'd',color="tab:blue",label="V")
v4= plt.plot(x4, y4, '^',color="tab:pink",label="V")
v5 = plt.plot(x5, y5, 's',color="tab:orange",label="V")
v6 = plt.plot(x6, y6, 'v',color="tab:cyan",label="V")

plt.plot(-6.5,3.5,"+",color="red",markersize=15)
plt.plot(4.5,5.5,"_",color="red",markersize=15)


ax.set_xlabel('$x$ [cm]')
ax.set_ylabel('$y$ [cm]')
ax.set(xlim=(-8, 8))
ax.set(ylim=(-8, 8))
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 0.7))

plt.vlines(-6,-3,3,colors="black", lw=5)
plt.vlines(4,-5,5,colors="black",lw=5)


plt.grid()

plt.show()





"Ajuste a una curva" es un poco ambiguo sin más detalles y sin saber si esos datos deberían ajustarse a algún modelo teórico concreto, pero si te refieres a ajustar a una parábola (a la que los datos parecen en principio ajustarse) puedes realizar un ajuste por mínimos cuadrados:
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import  Polynomial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x1 = [-0.4, -0.3, -0.2, -0.2, -0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.2, -0.3]
y1 = [-6, -5, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6]

x2 = [2.5, 2.3, 2.1, 1.8, 1.9, 2, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.4, 2.5]
y2 = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

x3 = [-2.7, -2.3, -2.2, -2.2, -2, -2, -2.1, -2.2, -2.4, -2.7]
y3 = [-5, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

x4 = [-4.6, -4.4, -4.2, -4, -4, -4.1, -4.2, -4.2, -4.5]
y4 = [-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

x5 = [-1.3, -1.2, -1.1, -1.1, -1.1, -1, -1, -1, -1.1, -1.2, -1.4]
y5 = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

x6 = [1.4, 1.3, 1.1, 1, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3]
y6 = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True


poli = Polynomial.fit(y1, x1, 2, domain=[min(y1), max(y1)])
print(poli)
fit_y, fit_x = poli.linspace(100)
plt.plot(fit_x, fit_y, color="tab:red")
v1 = plt.plot(x1, y1, 'o', color="tab:red", label="V")

poli = Polynomial.fit(y2, x2, 2, domain=[min(y2), max(y2)])
fit_y, fit_x = poli.linspace(100)
plt.plot(fit_x, fit_y, color="tab:green")
plt.plot(x2, y2, 'o', color="tab:green", label="V")

poli = Polynomial.fit(y3, x3, 2, domain=[min(y3), max(y3)])
fit_y, fit_x = poli.linspace(100)
plt.plot(fit_x, fit_y, color="tab:blue")
plt.plot(x3, y3, 'd', color="tab:blue", label="V")

poli = Polynomial.fit(y4, x4, 2, domain=[min(y4), max(y4)])
fit_y, fit_x = poli.linspace(100)
plt.plot(fit_x, fit_y, color="tab:pink")
v4 = plt.plot(x4, y4, '^', color="tab:pink", label="V")

poli = Polynomial.fit(y5, x5, 2, domain=[min(y5), max(y5)])
fit_y, fit_x = poli.linspace(100)
plt.plot(fit_x, fit_y, color="tab:orange")
v5 = plt.plot(x5, y5, 's', color="tab:orange", label="V")

poli = Polynomial.fit(y6, x6, 2, domain=[min(y6), max(y6)])
fit_y, fit_x = poli.linspace(100)
plt.plot(fit_x, fit_y, color="tab:cyan")
v6 = plt.plot(x6, y6, 'v', color="tab:cyan", label="V")

plt.plot(-6.5, 3.5, "+", color="red", markersize=15)
plt.plot(4.5, 5.5, "_", color="red", markersize=15)

ax.set_xlabel('$x$ [cm]')
ax.set_ylabel('$y$ [cm]')
ax.set(xlim=(-8, 8))
ax.set(ylim=(-8, 8))
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 0.7))

plt.vlines(-6, -3, 3, colors="black", lw=5)
plt.vlines(4, -5, 5, colors="black", lw=5)

plt.grid()

plt.show()



Edición
Había cometido un error tipográfico anteriormente por el que todos los polinomios tenía el dominio propio del primer conjunto de datos (todas las instancias de Polynomial recibían domain=[min(y1), max(y1)]). Lo he corregido, pero si te interesara que todas las curvas de ajuste tengan el mismo alto puedes extender el dominio de todos los polinomios, quedando la gráfica como la generada por mi error:


Obviamente es un ajuste, la linea no va a pasar por todos los puntos de tus datos experimentales. Si quieres que pase por todos ellos ya estaríamos hablando de interpolación y no de ajuste, para ello el módulo scipy.interpolate trae funciones muy útiles.
Por ejemplo usando una interpolación B-Spline:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

x1 = [-0.4, -0.3, -0.2, -0.2, -0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.2, -0.3]
y1 = [-6, -5, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6]

x2 = [2.5, 2.3, 2.1, 1.8, 1.9, 2, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.4, 2.5]
y2 = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

x3 = [-2.7, -2.3, -2.2, -2.2, -2, -2, -2.1, -2.2, -2.4, -2.7]
y3 = [-5, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

x4 = [-4.6, -4.4, -4.2, -4, -4, -4.1, -4.2, -4.2, -4.5]
y4 = [-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

x5 = [-1.3, -1.2, -1.1, -1.1, -1.1, -1, -1, -1, -1.1, -1.2, -1.4]
y5 = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

x6 = [1.4, 1.3, 1.1, 1, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3]
y6 = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

y1_smooth = np.linspace(min(y1), max(y1), 200)
x1_smooth = make_interp_spline(y1, x1, k=5)(y1_smooth)
plt.plot(x1_smooth, y1_smooth, color="tab:red")
v1 = plt.plot(x1, y1, 'o', color="tab:red", label="V")

y2_smooth = np.linspace(min(y2), max(y2), 200)
x2_smooth = make_interp_spline(y2, x2, k=5)(y2_smooth)
plt.plot(x2_smooth, y2_smooth, color="tab:green")
v2 = plt.plot(x2, y2, 'o', color="tab:green", label="V")

y3_smooth = np.linspace(min(y3), max(y3), 200)
x3_smooth = make_interp_spline(y3, x3, k=3)(y3_smooth)
plt.plot(x3_smooth, y3_smooth, color="tab:blue")
v3 = plt.plot(x3, y3, 'd', color="tab:blue", label="V")

y4_smooth = np.linspace(min(y4), max(y4), 200)
x4_smooth = make_interp_spline(y4, x4, k=5)(y4_smooth)
plt.plot(x4_smooth, y4_smooth, color="tab:pink")
v4 = plt.plot(x4, y4, '^', color="tab:pink", label="V")

y5_smooth = np.linspace(min(y5), max(y5), 200)
x5_smooth = make_interp_spline(y5, x5, k=5)(y5_smooth)
plt.plot(x5_smooth, y5_smooth, color="tab:orange")
v5 = plt.plot(x5, y5, 's', color="tab:orange", label="V")

y6_smooth = np.linspace(min(y6), max(y6), 200)
x6_smooth = make_interp_spline(y6, x6, k=5)(y6_smooth)
plt.plot(x6_smooth, y6_smooth, color="tab:cyan")
v6 = plt.plot(x6, y6, 'v', color="tab:cyan", label="V")

plt.plot(-6.5, 3.5, "+", color="red", markersize=15)
plt.plot(4.5, 5.5, "_", color="red", markersize=15)

ax.set_xlabel('$x$ [cm]')
ax.set_ylabel('$y$ [cm]')
ax.set(xlim=(-8, 8))
ax.set(ylim=(-8, 8))
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 0.7))

plt.vlines(-6, -3, 3, colors="black", lw=5)
plt.vlines(4, -5, 5, colors="black", lw=5)

plt.grid()

plt.show()



Observación: he ordenado previamente los puntos de cada conjunto de datos de menor a mayor en función del valor de la coordenada del eje y. Es simple de hacerlo con x1, y1 = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(x2, y2), key=lambda row: row[1]))) por ejemplo, pero para no complicar el código, simplemente  lo he harcodeado reescribiendo tus listas de datos iniciales. Esto es necesario para los métodos usados funcionen adecuadamente.


Perdón por la falta de detalles, era justamente un ajuste a una parábola lo que necesitaba, y el tip para ordenar las listas me va a ser muy util. Muchas gracias!

De nada y no te preocupes, la verdad es que nada más ver tu gráfica, a pesar de no haber muchos datos, da la impresión que un polinomio cuadrático se ajustará bastante bien a ellos... :)  Lo de la interpolación lo puse por si acaso, aunque ciertamente especificabas "ajuste", al comentar lo de "los puntos no respetan una función" me surgieron dudas y como son realmente tres lineas de código lo agregué por si acaso, supongo que lo dejaré por si a alguien le resulta útil.  Saludos.
